# How can I enable the reports menu in SQL databases

Tags: sql-server

according to this picture the reports menu is disabled.

[image]

how can I enable this menu.
I thought that maybe it depends on the version of my SQL server.so this is my SQL server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) 
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 8.1 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
```

Comment: It's probably permissions related.   This question should be moved to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: how can I do that??!

Comment: I think only a moderator can move it, but you can delete it and ask a new question there in the meantime.